# Importing Certificate to cacerts giving file I/O exception on Mac OS Mojave

Tags: java, terminal, jvm, ssl-certificate, keytool

Hello I am trying to import a certificate into cacerts on Mac OSX Mojave 10.14.4. I am using OpenJDK if that makes any difference.

My cert file is .p12.

Here is the path I tried to take

```
keytool -import -alias nulogix -keystore $(/usr/libexec/java_home)/jre/lib/security/cacerts -file/Users/user/Desktop/cert.p12
```

This gave me an key tool error

```
keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-12.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts (No such file or directory)
```

What is the correct path?

Comment: cacerts usually have read only permission for all users except admin/root. Try to run the same command as a superuser.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Figured it out.

Typing in

```
/usr/libexec/java_home
```

will give you the location of cacerts on your system.

Then you can either put that as part of your -keystore input or you can just simply do this

```
keytool -import -alias nulogix -keystore $(/usr/libexec/java_home)/lib/security/cacerts
  -file /Users/user/Desktop/cert.p12
```